# Radiobuttons in Python (TKinter)

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, radio-button

I am bust doing some homework and I am stuck on this exercise. The task is to create 12 labels in 3 columns with a radio button under each column. When a radio button is selected, the colour of the row above it needs to change. When the radio button is unselected then they change back to there original colour. When the program starts, none of the radio buttons must be selected.

I have two problems.

1. I cannot figure out how to start the program with all the radio buttons unselected. Currently, two are selected at once.
2. The functions that change the colour of the boxes seem to run when the program loads. They do not change back to their original colour.

Here is my code:

```
# Import the Tkinter functions
from Tkinter import *

# Create a window
the_window = Tk()
the_window.geometry('460x200')

# Give the window a title
the_window.title('Show Columns')

#Change first set colour
def change_first_set_colour():
    label1.configure(bg="blue")
    label2.configure(bg="blue")
    label3.configure(bg="blue")
    label4.configure(bg="blue")

#Change first set colour
def change_second_set_colour():
    label5.configure(bg="blue")
    label6.configure(bg="blue")
    label7.configure(bg="blue")
    label8.configure(bg="blue")

#Change first set colour
def change_third_set_colour():
    label9.configure(bg="blue")
    label10.configure(bg="blue")
    label11.configure(bg="blue")
    label12.configure(bg="blue")

#Create label1
label1 = Label(the_window, bg="grey", fg="black", width=20, height=2)
label1.place(x=5, y=5)

#Create label2
label2 = Label(the_window, bg="grey", fg="black", width=20, height=2)
label2.place(x=5, y=45)

#Create label3
label3 = Label(the_window, bg="grey", fg="black", width=20, height=2)
label3.place(x=5, y=85)

#Create label4
label4 = Label(the_window, bg="grey", fg="black", width=20, height=2)
label4.place(x=5, y=125)

#Create Radio Button 1
Radio_1 = Radiobutton(the_window,
                      text="First",
                      command=change_first_set_colour(),
                      value=1).place(x=50, y=165)

#Create label5
label5 = Label(the_window, bg="grey", fg="black", width=20, height=2)
label5.place(x=155, y=5)

#Create label6
label6 = Label(the_window, bg="grey", fg="black", width=20, height=2)
label6.place(x=155, y=45)

#Create label7
label7 = Label(the_window, bg="grey", fg="black", width=20, height=2)
label7.place(x=155, y=85)

#Create label8
label8 = Label(the_window, bg="grey", fg="black", width=20, height=2)
label8.place(x=155, y=125)

#Create Radio Button 2
Radio_2 = Radiobutton(the_window,
                      text="Second",
                      command=change_second_set_colour(),
                      value=2).place(x=180, y=165)

#Create label9
label9 = Label(the_window, bg="grey", fg="black", width=20, height=2)
label9.place(x=305, y=5)

#Create label10
label10 = Label(the_window, bg="grey", fg="black", width=20, height=2)
label10.place(x=305, y=45)

#Create label11
label11 = Label(the_window, bg="grey", fg="black", width=20, height=2)
label11.place(x=305, y=85)

#Create label12
label12 = Label(the_window, bg="grey", fg="black", width=20, height=2)
label12.place(x=305, y=125)

Radio_3 = Radiobutton(the_window,
                      text="Third",
                      command=change_third_set_colour(),
                      value=3).place(x=345, y=165)

#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Start the event loop to react to user inputs
the_window.mainloop()
```

PS: My university still uses Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot figure out how to start the program with all the radio
>   buttons unselected. Currently, two are selected at once.

Use variable with a value that does not match any of radio buttons' values (0 for example).

> The functions that change the colour of the boxes seem to run when the
>   program loads. They do not change back to their original colour.

pass the functions themselves, not return value of the function call. In other word, remove `()`

`command=change_third_set_colour()` -> `command=change_third_set_colour`

---

BTW, `place` should be called separately, otherwise `Radio_1`, `Radio_2`, `Radio_3` become `None` because `place` method returns `None`.

```
radio_var = IntVar(value=0)

Radio_1 = Radiobutton(the_window,
                      text="First",
                      variable=radio_var,  # <---
                      command=change_first_set_colour,  # <---
                      value=1)
Radio_1.place(x=50, y=165)  # <---

...

Radio_2 = Radiobutton(the_window,
                      text="Second",
                      variable=radio_var,  # <---
                      command=change_second_set_colour,  # <---
                      value=2)
Radio_2.place(x=180, y=165)  # <---

...

Radio_3 = Radiobutton(the_window,
                      text="Third",
                      variable=radio_var,  # <---
                      command=change_third_set_colour,  # <---
                      value=3)
Radio_3.place(x=345, y=165)  # <---
```

`change_first_set_colour`, `change_second_set_colour`, `change_third_set_colour` should be modified to reset other labels' color.

Answer (score 0):

1. I cannot figure out how to start the program with all the radio buttons unselected. Currently, two are selected at once.

   For this problem, first you need to make them as group using 'var'. you have given value, but also you should give the var to make them as group and get the value associated with them

       `var = IntVar()

       R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1,
                     command=sel)
   R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1,
                     command=sel)`

   And get the value using command implemetation like

       `def sel():
          selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())`

   Or you can get the color code in your case

2 The functions that change the colour of the boxes seem to run when the program loads. They do not change back to their original colour
    For This problem as I have specified above, you command method to set the new color and remember that before changing the color get the color of the label and save locally in class or global variable. then it will be helpful to revert back from new code older/original color